# Jquery cant select selected option in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box which is the selected option is automatically selected via axios in page load. And I want another function to get the selected option but what I get is a blank. Here is what I did.

The function that automatically selects the option

```
    function getOutsourcerManagerName(){
      axios.get(`/admin/ses/getManagersOutsourcer/${@json($ses->outsourcer)}`).then((res)=>{
          console.log(res)
          var manager = res.data
          $("#outsourcer_manager_name").empty()
          $("#outsourcer_manager_name").append("<option selected  value=''></option>");
            $("#outsourcer_division").val("")
            $("#outsourcer_department").val("")
            $("#outsourcer_tel").val("")
            $("#outsourcer_zip").val("")
            $("#outsourcer_address1").val("")
            $("#outsourcer_address2").val("")
            for (let i = 0; i < manager.length; i ++){
             //this one selects the option
             var selected = manager[i]['id'] ==  @json($ses->outsourcer) ? 'selected' : ''
             $("#outsourcer_manager_name").append("<option selected data-manager-id='" + manager[i]['id'] + "' value='" + manager[i]['name'] + "'>" + manager[i]['name'] + "</option>");
          }
        })
    }
```

The function I wrote and not working

```
    function getWorkersPerManagerOutsourcerManagerName(){
      var select = document.getElementById('outsourcer_manager_name');
      var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
      console.log(value)
    }
```

the log prints a empty/blank value. can someone tell me what did i miss? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please come back once you have figured out what you need to select and what you get from the server

Comment: 1) does your code work if you remove the async part (and just call `$("#outsourcer_manager_name").append("<option...` with hardcoded values)?   2) is your  `getWorkersPerManagerOutsourcerManagerName` running *before* the async call has completed?